# When Peter Parker say "Know", what exactly is he referring to?

Tags: spider-man, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021), Peter Parker speaks to MJ on phone:

> Peter: Ever since I got bit by that spider...I've only had one week
> where my life has felt normal. Or kind of normal, I guess. And...
> that was when you found out. Because then everyone that was in my life
> that I wanted to **know**, knew.

When Peter Parker say "Know", what exactly is he referring to ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peter is referring to [MJ learning and confirming his identity as Spider-Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiXg6MTpzbs) (*"that was when you found out"*), and hence that he no longer needs to lie to her about his whereabout and actions.

The line could read

> "*Because then everyone that was in my life* [including my aunt, best friend and would-be girlfriend] *that I wanted to know* [my secret identity as Spider-Man], *knew* [my secret identity as Spider-Man]"

The other people in this sentence referring to his aunt and best friend.